# Как исключить наследуемые атрибуты в определенных случаях

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Есть к примеру два класса с атрибутами (это модели sqlalchemy):

```
class A:

    param_1 = None
    param_2 = None

class B(A):

    param_3 = None
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы класс В наследовался от А. Но в отдельном случае, мне не нужно, чтобы наследовались атрибуты класса А. Можно как-то это реализовать? Или удалять атрибуты у экземпляра класса?

Comment: Попробуйте покопать в сторону мета-классов python

Comment: Можно перезаписывать в None - вопрос, зачем?

Comment: @strawdog None это просто пример. Выше написано, что это модели ORM

Comment: Я так понимаю из-за того, что это модель SQLAlchemy, она не сможет ассоциировать мета-класс. И мне придется использовать raw sql